# grub-efi refuses to chainload Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, grub, uefi

I have installed LMDE (with grub in MBR) after I installed Windows 8.1. I then installed the `grub-efi` package and added the custom Windows options:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Windows" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root A89A-7F4C
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}
menuentry "Windows (backup bootloader)" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root A89A-7F4C
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi
}
```

These are basically a leftover from my older Ubuntu setup. However, grub is refusing to load them, complaining about the invalid signature. What do I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "invalid signature" complaint sounds like a Secure Boot error. I'm not sure where Ubuntu is with this, but some versions of GRUB refuse to chainload Windows when Secure Boot is active, which necessitates either [disabling Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) or using another boot manager (such as the one that's built into most EFIs, [gummiboot,](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) or [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead of or in addition to GRUB. The easiest solution is probably to disable Secure Boot. If you want to keep Secure Boot active, the simplest solution is likely to be to install rEFInd; however, you should read the [rEFInd documentation on Secure Boot,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) since you'll need to jump through some extra hoops to get it to work.

---

***EDIT:*** First, upon re-reading your description, you mention both GRUB in the MBR (which implies a BIOS-mode GRUB installation) and the `grub-efi` package (which is the EFI version of GRUB). Your Windows GRUB stanzas are clearly intended for an EFI-mode GRUB. If you've got both installed, then it's conceivable that you're launching the BIOS-mode version of GRUB by accident, which would fail when launching the EFI-mode Windows entries. If this is the root cause, you'll need to find a way to force the EFI version of GRUB to launch. You may be able to use your computer's built-in boot manager or firmware boot settings to do this; or you may need to wipe out the GRUB in the MBR by typing `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=440 count=1` in a Terminal window. Be *very careful* with this command, though; omitting or mistyping a parameter can cause serious damage to your hard disk. The `bs=` and `count=` options are particularly important.

If you're launching the EFI version of GRUB and you still have problems, try the following entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` (and run `sudo update-grub` after making the change):

```
menuentry "Windows" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Change `(hd0,gpt1)` to whatever GRUB's identifier is for your EFI System Partition (ESP). Also, if you've run Boot Repair in the past (as your example entries suggest you may have done), you may need to change `bootmgfw.efi` to `bkpbootmgfw.efi`. It's conceivable that the FAT filesystem code in your existing entries is wrong, or that there's some other detail that's wrong, which is why I'm suggesting using this entry, which has worked for me in the past, as a model. (These GRUB chainloader entries are notoriously finicky.)

If that fails, try using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) If that can boot Windows, you can install the Debian version of rEFInd on your hard disk. It will then take over from GRUB, which you shouldn't need any more. rEFInd is much easier to manually maintain than GRUB; GRUB is easy only because of a boatload of configuration scripts that  do most of the customization that's required for most installations.

Comment: I don't have Secure Boot active.

Comment: Please see my new suggestions in my edit.

Comment: I did what you said, and turns out grub wasn't in EFI at all, I probably didn't run some command I had to run :( So I used my Ubuntu CD to run boot-repair and now things work (although Boot Repair messed up my DNS configuration so that Network Manager doesn't write the right nameservers to resolv.conf for some reason). All in all, I consider it a mixed success. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` helped with the DNS problem, BTW.

Comment: one can simply copy the refind.efi onto the FAT32 partition of windows and boot it via grub like the real windows.efi thing. rEFInd is excellent, everyone should have it in his toolchest. Now I need to figure out why neither grub2 nor refind can boot win8.1 - maybe the BIOSBOOT partn has gone haywire, its filesystem is "unknown" -- should it not be FAT32 too ? In my case, refind does boot a win.efi - which is however some weird RECOVERY system which of course, in due time, fails too on me all the time.  But it goes to show  that refind does indeed boot up those windows.efi  binaries.

Comment: I guess I will have to remove grub altogether and put the win bootloader back in place somehow. The win disk booted after I originally had used clonezilla to make a disk clone and then win booted OK.